# Portal Achievements Not Unlocking

Tags: steam, achievements, portal

I have limited internet access and played through Portal without being online. As a result, several of the achievements didn't unlock. I later went back and played through a second time online to try and get some, but they wouldn't unlock. Some of these achievements include: "Cup Cake", "Fruit Cake", "Vanilla Crazy Cake", and "Camera Shy". How can I unlock these achievements if they won't register?

Comment: Which version is this? PC, 360, PS3?

Comment: PC (Windows Vista)

Comment: Weird, when I play games on Steam offline, achievements unlock as soon as I get internet access.

Comment: since you probably already "earned" the achievements offline there might be a synchronization issue, so maybe this is something to contact steam support about

Answer (score 2):

For achievements like Camera Shy I found I had to play through the **entire game without loading from a save game** (I can't remember if I died or not - probably not).

If you save/load the game the count is probably reset (or the other completed levels are spawned intact, with cameras, who knows)

Comment: Tried to finish this myself, and somehow only got to 17 when I used new game/load to get to the specific maps. I had taken care of all the cameras in that game session. However when I restarted the game, did one of the chambers and checked the achievement again I was back at 1. I believe this is a bug, so it's required that you do it in one playthrough or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

Open the developer console (the `` `key; you'll have to enable it in the Advanced menu of the Keyboard settings) and enter in`developer 1`(possibly`developer 4`) and try to do something that would count towards an achievement like Camera Shy. Usually some text will pop up in the console about it, and it might give you some insight as to why they aren't unlocking.

Make sure that you aren't using the commentary mode as well, which disables them. Worst case, perhaps try a full reinstall of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Portal is unfortunately very prone to such errors.

If it does not take its natural course the following day, i.e. Steam syncs and achievements appear, then it will probably not ever.

Contact Valve support and let them reset that specific achievement.
Then you can do them from scratch.